# Any model integrable but not separable?

Tags: classical-mechanics, hamiltonian-formalism, phase-space, integrable-systems, integrals-of-motion

In textbooks on classical mechanics, the exactly solvable models are all separable. Is there any model integrable but not separable?

Comment: Related to [Is a system integrable if and only if its Hamilton-Jacobi equation is separable?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/291511/)

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/291511/2451 and links therein.

Answer (score 1):

The Toda-Lattice is integrable but not seperable https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toda_lattice#Integrability

Im still learning all of this so I‘am unable to tell you why, but that‘s the example my professor gave.