# Itzykson Zuber Quantum Field Theory: meaning of integrable system

Tags: classical-mechanics, coordinate-systems, hamiltonian-formalism, phase-space, integrable-systems

Here is a part of the book Quantum Field Theory by  Itzykson and Zuber:

[image: Page 6]

[image: Page 7]

I have two questions:

1. what does the author mean that equation (1-30) form and integrable system, and why?
2. what is the accurate meaning of last paragraph? Why are p' and q' constants of motion and how does eliminating procedure works?

Comment: [WP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrable_system), and [also](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/291845/66086).